# Wrote a trigger to prevent record deletion, now need help with test class

Tags: trigger, class, code-coverage

I'm a newbie when it comes to writing triggers and test classes. I've written a trigger that prevents the deletion of a record on a custom object, System_Integration__c, when a date field (Deactivation_Date__c) on the custom object is populated with a date. Here is the code for the trigger, which seems to work (the System Integration record is prevented from being deleted with the appropriate error message). However, I have 0% code coverage, and I don't know really how to go about writing a test class for the trigger.

The code for the trigger is as follows:

```
trigger preventDelete on System_Integration__c (before delete)
{
   for(System_Integration__c obj: Trigger.old)
   {
     if((obj.Deactivation_Date__c) <> NULL )
     {
        obj.addError('You can not delete this record since it has a Deactivation Date added.');
     }
   }
}
```

Can anyone guide/assist me at this point? Thanks. P.S., sorry if the code isn't formatted per developer guidelines as stackexchange apparently autoformats these posts.

Comment: Stackexchange uses markdown (well, one flavor thereof at least) to format things. I've fixed the formatting for your code block this time, and you may find the [formatting help page](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to be useful. I don't think it goes over basic code formatting. Essentially, any line in a question or answer that starts with 4 spaces denotes a 'block' of code. The easy way to format a code block is to copy/paste, select the entire block, and then hit the 'code' button (open + closed curly brackets) in the editor to insert 4 spaces at the start of each line.

Comment: using `<pre></pre>` or highlighting your entire code block and pressing ctrl + k also accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: As for getting started with writing unit tests, the [unit testing module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing) on Trailhead is probably where you should start (Trailhead is better suited for becoming familiar with the basics than this site is).

Comment: Give the trailhead modules a blast, and if you still have trouble, paste your test class in here and we'll help you nit-pick it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link that shows a fairly simple trigger and its test code: [Create test class for trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_To_Test_Your_Apex_Triggers)

The short version is that you'll need to create a class that creates a record of the type that matches your trigger.  Next, you delete the record.  You'll want to do this for a record with a deactivation date and one without if you want 100% coverage of the code shown above.

Note the initial "@isTest(seeAllData=false)" line and also the Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() lines. Assert lines aren't required, but they're a good practice.  100% coverage doesn't mean everything worked as expected.  Take the time to make sure you get the expected results.